# Can Rest Assured Start An In-Memory Server?

Tags: java, jersey, rest-assured

Jersey Test Framework has an option to start an In-Memory REST server as part of the test setup.

Can Rest-Assured start up an In-Memory REST server too?

Comment: It is only a client. No server.

Comment: If you can add info on if the two frameworks conflict in any way or how they work together then this is a good enough answer.

Comment: You can't used Rest Assured with the In-memory provider of the Jersey Test Framework because Rest Assured makes actual network requests, while the in-memory provider does not. It implements a Jersey client connector that call the backend directly, without any network requests.